# How to use mercurial's bugzilla extension with 3.6+ bugzilla?

Tags: mercurial, bug-tracking, bugzilla

I want to use bugzilla extension to keep track of commits in my bugs.

I have followed the instructions there http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html (§ bugzilla), and my hgrc is like this:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bugzilla =

[hooks]
# run bugzilla hook on every change pulled or pushed in here
incoming.bugzilla = python:hgext.bugzilla.hook

[bugzilla]
host = localhost # mysql server where bugzilla database lives
db = bugzilla3       # database to connect to
user = bugzilla3     # user to connect to database as
password = blah   # user's password
version = 3.6.3  # version of bugzilla installed
bzuser = valid_user@domain.tld    # fallback bugzilla user name to record comments with
```

my commit looks like this:

```
useful commit informations
bug: 123
```

But that doesn't do anything.

So my questions are:

- is the extension compatible with bugzilla 3.6.3 (I'm using mercurial 1.7.5) ?
- is my configuration ok ?
- is there any log that mercurial produce to find what's wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the XML-RPC interface. From the hook script itself an example configuration file for this is:

> ```
> [bugzilla]
> bzurl=http://my-project.org/bugzilla
> user=bugmail@my-project.org
> password=plugh
> version=xmlrpc
> template=Changeset {node|short} in {root|basename}.
>          {hgweb}/{webroot}/rev/{node|short}\n
>          {desc}\n
> strip=5
>
> [web]
> baseurl=http://my-project.org/hg
> ```

It also states

> If your Bugzilla is version 3.2 or above, you are strongly
>      recommended to use the XMLRPC access method instead.

So this may move you forward a little faster.